# How to handle this context? (The user should only select a quantity value based on the capacity of the registration type)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a select menu form for a user select the quantity that he wants for each registration type. I have a rule RegistrationTypeQuantity to validate the quantity introduced by the user, basically for the validation pass, the user needs to select at least the quantity for 1 registration type and the user needs to select a quantity value between min_participants and max_participants.

RegistrationTypeQuantity rule passes():

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $count = array_sum($value);

        if($count == 0){
            return false;
        }
        foreach($value as $key=>$v) {

            $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name',$key)->first();
            if ( !$rtype ){
                return false;
            }

            if ( $v != 0 && ($v < $rtype->min_participants || $v > $rtype->max_participants) ){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But Im with a doubt, each registration type has a capacity, for example the conference with id "1" has two registration types (general and plus). The registration type "general" has capacity of 100 and the registration type "plus" has capacity of 50. My doubt is how to also include the logic about the capacity of each registration type in the validation.

So for example, if registration type "general" has capacity 10 and there are 10 participants registered in the registration type "general" and the user introduce in the source code fore example the value "10" for the registration type "general" and "1" for the registration type plus and click Next the validation show an error saying that the registration type is out of capacity.

Also, if registration type "general" has capacity 10, min_participants 1, and max participants 3, and there are 8 participants registered in the registration type "general" and the user selected in the select menu the value "3" because it is a value between the min_participants and max_participants it should show a validation error because the user should only be allowed to select quantity 1 or 2 because, 8 participants + 3 = 11 and the total capacity is 10. So it should show also an error saying out of capacity in this case.

Do you know how this context can be achieved?

Select menu code for the user to select the quantity for each registration type of the conference:

```
@foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
<li>
    <div>
        <span>{{$rtype->name}}</span>
    </div>

    @if(min($rtype->max_participants, ($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants->count())) == 0)
        Out of capacity
    @else
        <select
                id="rtype_{{ $rtype->id }}"
                data-price="{{ $rtype->price }}"
                name="rtypes[{{ $rtype->name }}]">
            <option value="0">0</option>

            @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= min($rtype->max_participants, ($rtype->capacity - $rtype->participants->count())); $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>
    @endif

    <span>X {{$rtype->presentPrice()}}
        €</span>
</li>
@endforeach
```

RegistrationController storeQuantity() method that is used to store the quantities for each registration type selected by the user in the select menu above:

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'rtypes' => ['required', 'array', new RegistrationTypeQuantity],
    ]);

    $conference = RegistrationType::where('id', $id)->first()->conference;
    $participantsCount = $conference->participants()->count();


    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'quantitiesError');
    }
    $rtypeQuantities = $request->get('rtypes');

    $total = 0;

    $selectedRtypes = [];

    foreach ($rtypeQuantities as $rtypeName => $quantity) {

        if ($quantity) {
            $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name', $rtypeName)->firstOrFail();
            $price = $rtype->price;

            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['price'] = $price;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
            $total += $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'];
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['total'] = $total;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions'] = $rtype->questions;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['id'] = $rtype->id;
        }
    }

    if($selectedRtypes){
        Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
        Session::put('customQuestions', $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions']);
        Session::put('total', $total);
    }

    return redirect(route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
public function rules(){

    $generalMax = $this->generalMaxAllowed();

    $plusMax = $this->plusMaxAllowed();

    return [
        rtypes.general => 'sometimes|integer|min:1|max:'.$generalMax,
        rtypes.plus => 'required_without:rtypes.general|integer|min:1|max:'.$plusMax

    ];

}

protected function generalMaxAllowed(){
    $allowedMax = 5; //in general we allowed max 5 participants for general seat

    $remain = $generalTotalSeatCapacity - $generalParticipantsCount; 

    return ($remain >= $allowedMax) ? $allowedMax : $remain;
}

protected function plusMaxAllowed(){
    $allowedMax = 3; //in general we allowed max 3 participants for plus seat

    $remain = $plusTotalSeatCapacity - $plusParticipantsCount;

    return ($remain >= $allowedMax) ? $allowedMax : $remain;
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on comments (Not Tested)

```
public function rules($request){

    $rules['rtypes'] = 'required|array';

    $fields = [];

    $count = 0;

    foreach($request->rtypes as $key => $value){

        $minMaxValues = $this->minMax($key);

        if($count == count($request->rtypes) - 1){ //last type validation then add required_without_all validation

            $requiredWithoutAll = implode(',', $fields);

            $required = 'required_without_all:'. $requiredWithoutAll;

        }else{
            $fields[] = $rtype;

            $required = 'sometimes';
        }

        $rules['rtypes.' . $key] = $required .'|integer|min:'. $minMaxValues[0].'|max:'.$minMaxValues[1];

        $count++;
    }

    return $rules;

}

//custom message pass it to your validation

public function messages($request){
    $messages = [];

    foreach($request->rtypes as $key => $value){

        $messages['rtypes.'. $key.'.max'] = "Out of capacity";

    }

    return $messages;
}


protected function minMax($type){

    $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name',$type)->first();

    if ( !$rtype ){
        return [1,0]; // return min 1 and max 0, means that validation will be fail
    }

    //get $participantsCount for each type from db

    $max =  ($participantsCount == 0) ? $rtype->max_participants : ($rtype->max_participants - $participantsCount); 

    $min =  ($max == 0) ? 1 : $rtype->min_participants;

    return [$min, $max];
}
```

Use this rules in Validator like this. You need to add all these functions in your controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules($request), $this->messages($request));
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have a custom rule to validate the quantity introduced by the user and I use it like " $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'rtypes' => ['required', 'array', new RegistrationTypeQuantity],
        ]);
". To test your code is necessary to create other rule?

Comment: I updated the question with the storeQuantities() that is used to store in session the quantities by the user in the select menu for each registration type.

Comment: when you add code then add full code. now again you have not added `RegistrationTypeQuantity` code. How do we know what you are doing there. It is always good to add your full code in question.

Comment: Thanks, the RegistrationTpeQuantity has the passes() that is the passes() that is in the question.

Comment: in your validation, i could not see the validation with remaining seat. you can try my code and yes you need to replace your validation code with my code

Comment: Thanks, but the RegistrationTypeQuantity passes() has some rules that are necessary to have also for the user to select the quantity for each registration type. Basically for the validation pass, the user needs to select at least the quantity for 1 registration type and the user needs to select a quantity value between min_participants and max_participants. My doubt is how to also include this context of the capacity of each registration type. But the other rules are also necessary.

Comment: first validation it will work `select at least the quantity for 1 registration type` for min and max participant. add an extra condition `generalSeatRemain` and `plusSeatRemain` that if suppose general max 5 seat can be booked by user and there are more than 5 seat available then the max validation should be 5, if not then remaining less than 5

Comment: Thanks, but Im not understanding how your code replaces the passes() method of the question. And a registration type can have the name "general", "plus" but also other names, its the conference creator that enters the name of the registration types for his conference.

Comment: ok, you mean your types is dynamic 'general', 'plus', 'diamond' like this ? Let me change the code. do you have number of participants booked in `RegistrationType` like min and max ?

Comment: Thanks, yes the registration type name is dynamic. The min_participants and max_participants are columns of the registration_types table. For example, if for the registration type "general" the min_participants is 1 and max_participants is 3, a user that is doing a registration in the conference can only select a quantity for the registration type "general" between 1 and 3.

Comment: Thanks, but so I have a custom RegistrationTypeQuantity rule that has the passes() and message() methods. Your code with the rules() method should be placed in the custom rule file?

Comment: updated answer check it, rules and messages function need a `$request` as parameter

Comment: Thanks with " $registrationsCount = $conference->participants()->count();" is possible to get the total number of participants in the conference, but what is necessary is get the number of participants of each registration type of the conference. But with " $registrationsCount = $conference->participants()->registration_type->count();" it shows "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough::$registration_type
". Do you know why?

Comment: In the Conference model there is " public function participants(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Participant', 'App\Registration', 'conference_id');
    }".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177559/discussion-between-rkj-and-john).

Comment: The registration type "general" has capacity 10 and there are 10 participants registered in the registration type "general". So in the select menu for the registration type only appears "0" but if the user introduce in the source code fore example "10" for the registration type "general" and "1" for the registration type plus and click Next, the dd($rules) using your code shows "array:2 [▼ 
"rtypes.50" => "sometimes|integer|min:1|max:0" 
"rtypes.1" => "sometimes|integer|min:1|max:0" 
]".

Comment: But the validation passes, but it should not because the user selected quantity 10 for "general" but the registration type "general" is out of capacity. So it should appear a validation error but it dont appear and so the user is redirected to the registration page with a incorrect quantity value.